# Is SOD(A^b) % mod == SOD(bigmod(A,b,mod))?

Tags: c++11, number-theory, modular-arithmetic, bigmod

I have to calculate **A^b** where A^b can be a huge number then find The SOD(Sum of divisors) of that number.

So, If I calculate **SOD(bigmod(A,b,mod))** will this return the same value as **SOD(A^b) % mod**

Asking for this As I am getting WA and could not get where I mistaken...

Link to the  [Problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/infinitum17/challenges/divisor-exploration-2)